# How to use variables \ macros with Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I try to use the macros / variables in the following way, but then I get an error. Can you advice please?

```
#define AnnotateDir "C:\Users\new_skin\Annotate\project"
#define AnnotateUserInstallAppData "{userappdata}\Annotate3"


[Files]
Source: {AnnotateDir}\bin\gm_annotate.exe; DestDir: {app}; Flags:  ignoreversion  external
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing `#` char before the variable name which is used to [`emit defined variable value`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=emit) during script preprocessing stage. You can fix your script this way:

```
#define AnnotateDir "C:\Users\new_skin\Annotate\project"  

[Files]
Source: {#AnnotateDir}\bin\gm_annotate.exe; DestDir: {app}; Flags: ignoreversion external
```

It looks quite misleading, but e.g. the `{app}` constant will remain after preprocessing whilst your defined variable will be replaced by its value, so that's why they have different notation in script.

Comment: You're welcome! Just a hint. If you'd like to see the preprocessed script, where all your defined variables are replaced, you can add line like `#expr SaveToFile("c:\PreprocessedScript.iss")` at the end of your script and you will get it saved into that specified file.