# Constant defined using Inno Setup preprocessor #define is not recognised in ExpandConstant

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to set up an install file that (optionally) installs .NET 5 if it's not already installed.
However, I'm having trouble defining the version of .NET to install in a constant.

My script is set up like this

```
#define DotNetVersion "5"
...
[Tasks]   
Name: "dotnet"; Description: "{cm:DotNet}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:Prerequisites}"
...

[Files]
Source: "..\Dependencies\{#DotNetInstallFile}"; DestDir: {tmp}; \
    Flags: deleteafterinstall; AfterInstall: InstallDotNet; \
    Check: NetNotInstalled(ExpandConstant('{DotNetVersion}')); Tasks: "dotnet"
```

When I try running the resulting install file I get the following error:

> Internal error: Expression error 'Internal error: Unknown constant "DotNetVersion"'

[image: Error box stating: 'Internal error: Unknown constant "DotNetVersion"']

The function `NetNotInstalled` works correctly if I replace `ExpandConstant('{DotNetVersion}')` with `'5'`, but I want to easily be able to change this without modifying more than the defined constants.

I don't get what's wrong here. The Inno Setup docs state that this *should* be valid.
Using the same constant for any other function seems to work flawlessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable [defined using Inno Setup preprocessor](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=define) is not [Inno Setup constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts). Calling [`ExpandConstant` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_expandconstant) on it has no effect.

To expand preprocessor variable (or any [expression](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=expressions)), you can use `{#VariableOrExpression}` syntax. It's an [inline preprocessor directive call](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=directives), where, when no directive is explicitly specified, the [`emit`](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=emit) is implied. So the `{#VariableOrExpression}` is the same as `{#emit VariableOrExpression}`. And as every preprocessor construct, it's evaluated on compile time (contrary to `ExpandConstant`).

You actually do that correctly already with `{#DotNetInstallFile}`, so do the same with `DotNetVersion`:

```
Source: "..\Dependencies\{#DotNetInstallFile}"; \
    DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: deleteafterinstall; AfterInstall: InstallDotNet; \
    Check: NetNotInstalled('{#DotNetVersion}'); Tasks: "dotnet"
```

See also [How to use variables \ macros with Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17881486/850848)